# Properties of transaction hashes

Tags: transactions, hash

I am trying to find more information about the properties/format of transaction hashes.
It looks like they all start with **o** followed by *n/p/o*, they are base58 encoded and are 51 characters long. Is that correct? Does somebody have more information about tx hash format in Tezos?
Thanks!

Comment: In addition to arvidj answer, I would add a link to https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/merge_requests/1528 which does explain the generation of the version bytes (the prefixes `B`, `o`, etc). It is related to the operation payloads.

Answer (score 4):

I was unable to find a complete answer, but here are some pointers. First, to clarify, I think you're asking about the format of operation hashes. A block consists of a set of operations. An operation can be for instance a transaction (transfer tokens), a delegation, contract creations... The prefix for blocks is *B*, for operations *o*. As you write, operations are base58 encoded and 51 characters long. This is declared in the Tezos source code [here](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/src/lib_crypto/operation_hash.ml).

Indeed, looking at [a block](https://tzstats.com/BMPggYM3JuxPKPKmjVUKtcgTNkGBi4K2Y6ME8Qb15HKXeCt1LgA) all the hash of all operations starts with *o* followed by n/p/o, but I've yet to find the reason why.